# Firebase database webapp read all the names of the users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From the Firebase Database, I'm trying to get all the names of the users in my web app. This is my Database structure:
[image]

In my Name table, I'm trying to get all the names (`A`, `B` ...). This is what I've been trying:

My html:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
<input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />
<button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
<div>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table_body">
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.4.1/firebase.js"></script> 
<script>
   var config = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyBYa4OCyyWNzTpWYHA5KeQ",
     authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "example",
     storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "77687691833822",
   };
   firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script> 
<script src="log.js"></script>
```

And the `log.js` is:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (user != null) {
            var email_id = user.email;

            var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
            rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
                var name = snap.child("Name").val();
                $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>");
            });
        }

    } else {

    }
});

function login() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
        //...
    });

}
```

But it isn't showing any data from the database. I'm making some mistake somewhere but not sure what it is. Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using console.log() to see if you're getting the values you expect in your database listener?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I did. And I'm not getting any value.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: In addition, check the JavaScript console of your browser to see if there is any relevant error message. For example: a message about Permission Denied would mean that you simply don't have access to the data, which means the problem is not in the code, but in your security rules.